# Input of big number to avoid NumberFormatException

Tags: java, input, long-integer, numberformatexception

I have to control input from 1 to 9999999999 (that represents the registration number of school)
The primitive type long can only hold up to about 2.000.000.000, how can i store numbers of this size?

Comment: What about long long? Although it is a difficult question to answer accurately without details like which language you are using.

Comment: Store the "number" as a string. If it's not a number in the sense of needing to perform math on it, then it doesn't need to be stored as a numeric type.

Comment: I have to make some controls on the number, I can't store String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), the `long` data type can hold values from -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, using 64 bits. It should be able to hold 9,999,999,999. Are you sure that you are treating that value as a `long` in all places?

Comment: you're right, but if I try creating a variable like:
long max = 9999999999;
it makes error: integer number too big

Comment: Try long max = 9999999999L; The 'L' at the end tells Java that it's a long literal, not a integer literal.